# Laravel - OAuth2 and Facebook

Tags: php, android, facebook, laravel, oauth

I'm developing a RESTful API with Laravel and I would like to achieve the following scenario with OAuth (I'm using the following package: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel):

1. A user logs into Facebook and grants permission using his mobile device;
2. The mobile device sends the Facebook access token to my API and OAuth generates my application-specific access token and returns it to the user.

I have already implemented the password flow for local accounts. Could somebody explain me how to achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i haven't tried your mentioned package, but i was successful using https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel. the examples there should get you started with ease.

like this FB implementation:

```
/**
 * Login user with facebook
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function loginWithFacebook() {

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

        $message = 'Your unique facebook user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array().
        dd($result);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}
```